# Using an api (rito api) with java (android)

Tags: java, android, json

I have this url: https://euw.api.riotgames.com/api/lol/EUW/v1.4/summoner/by-name/motschel123?api_key=RGAPI-6A9B210B-31F9-4AD9-8393-1CF3DA6E10EF

And I want to get the data on the website:

```
try {
    URL url = new URL("https://euw.api.riotgames.com/api/lol/" + region + "/v1.4/summoner/by-name/" + summonerN + "?api_key=" + apiCode);
    parseJSON(url);
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Error creating URL",
                   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} catch (Exception e) {
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Error reading URL",
                   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

And the function `parseJSON(URL url)`:

```
public void parseJSON(URL url) throws Exception{
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));

    String inputLine;
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), inputLine,
                       Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    in.close();
}
```

But it doesn't work and just throws an `Exception`.
How can I fix it?

Comment: use retrofi library, it will be very easy to retrive data from dynamic url

Comment: @Akashkumar   retrofiT?

Comment: find the answer below. i provided

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Retrofit library for retriving and parsing data from URL or Dynmaic URL. You have give base URL and varying part too via variable. You have to create getter setter of vbarialbe which is being received.

Please follow this tutorial
[Retrofit tutorial](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-getting-started-and-android-client)

[Retrofit with QUery URL](http://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-add-multiple-query-parameter-with-querymap)

You can create getter setter of via this site

[create gettter and setter](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/)